# How to remove multiple fields from index?

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to remove multiple fields from index for example ('person_full','company_full'). Using `ES: 5.6.14`

To delete one field -> following code is working well

```
POST firma-2019.04/_update_by_query?conflicts=proceed
{
    "script": {
        "source": "ctx._source.remove('person_full')",
        "lang": "painless"
    }
}
```

But I would like to delete multiple fields at once and this code does not work.

```
POST firma-2019.04/_update_by_query?conflicts=proceed
{
    "script": {
        "source": "ctx._source.remove('person_full','company_full')",
        "lang": "painless"
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your Help

Answer (score 8):

The below query should work:

```
POST firma-2019.04/_update_by_query?conflicts=proceed
{
    "script": {
        "source": "ctx._source.remove('person_full');ctx._source.remove('company_full')",
        "lang": "painless"
    }
}
```

To delete more fields add more remove statements in the script.

Answer (score 2):

You dont want to update all the documents in the index. Imagine if you have millions, the script will update all the documents. Instead add an additional check to see if field exists before trying to remove it.

Below will only update the documents and remove the fields where either `person_full` or `company_full` exists.

```
POST firma-2019.04/_update_by_query?conflicts=proceed
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "person_full"
          }
        },
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "company_full"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.remove('person_full'); ctx._source.remove('company_full');",
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}
```

Comment: TheUnknown, thank you, one question. How should see should statement in your query, if person_full & company_full are arrays?

Comment: The field type doesn’t matter for exists query. All it does it check if the field exists. So above should work as is.

Comment: your script is working well with no array fields. but with array fields i get:                  {
  "took": 5,
  "timed_out": false,
  "total": 0,
  "updated": 0,
  "deleted": 0,
  "batches": 0,
  "version_conflicts": 0,
  "noops": 0,
  "retries": {
    "bulk": 0,
    "search": 0
  },
  "throttled_millis": 0,
  "requests_per_second": -1,
  "throttled_until_millis": 0,
  "failures": []
}

Comment: No, above works for array too, exists doesnt care  about field type unless you have a nested field. May be if you add your mapping and example document, i can help.